# How to make a multiblock structure in minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

In Minecraft 1.10, I have a string of commands as a floor crafting setup, but I want to be able to have these multiple command blocks be placed into a world with a single command. Is this possible?

Comment: Go search up something called one command contraptions. That may be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

There is a way that allows you to combine multiple command blocks into one structure, but it is a little difficult. The link provided by David Cole creates a command that works like this. This tutorial is for 1.9/1.10 using the Passengers tag.
The command works by spawning Falling Sand that has more falling sand on top. Each falling sand block is a command block that functions like a command block. Those command blocks have your commands in them. You can write one of these by typing in this format:

```
/summon FallingSand <x> <y> <z> {Block: "minecraft:command_block", Time: 1,  TileEntityData: {Command: <first command>, auto: 1}, Passengers: [ ({id: FallingSand, Block: "minecraft:command_block", Time: 1, TileEntityData: {Command: <next command>, auto: 1}} x number of commands)]}
```

You would put `Block: "minecraft:command_block", Time: 1, TileEntityData: {Command: <first command>, auto: 1}` in Passengers as many times as you have commands (separated by commas). So, a command could look like this:

```
summon FallingSand ~2 ~4 ~ {Block:"minecraft:redstone_block",Time:1,Riding:¬
{id:FallingSand,Block:"minecraft:command_block",Time:1,TileEntityData:{Command:summon FallingSand ~2 ~1 ~ {Block:"minecraft:redstone_block",Time:1,Riding:¬
{id:FallingSand,Time:1,Block:"minecraft:command_block",TileEntityData:{Command:summon FallingSand ~2 ~2 ~ {Block:"minecraft:redstone_block",Time:1,Riding:¬
{id:FallingSand,Time:1,Block:"minecraft:command_block",TileEntityData:{Command:summon FallingSand ~1 ~ ~ {Block:"minecraft:redstone_block",Time:1,Riding:¬
{id:FallingSand,Block:"minecraft:redstone_block",Time:1,Riding:¬
{id:FallingSand,Block:"minecraft:redstone_block",Time:1,Riding:¬
{id:FallingSand,Time:1,Block:"minecraft:redstone_block"}}}}},Riding:¬
{id:FallingSand,Block:"minecraft:command_block",Time:1,TileEntityData:{Command:setblock ~-5 ~-2 ~ stone_button 2},Riding:¬
{id:FallingSand,Block:"minecraft:command_block",Time:1,TileEntityData:{Command:setblock ~-4 ~-1 ~1 minecraft:command_block 0 replace {Command:effect @e slowness 30 25}},Riding:¬
{id:FallingSand,Block:"minecraft:command_block",Time:1,TileEntityData:{Command:setblock ~-3 ~ ~ minecraft:unpowered_repeater 5},Riding:¬
{id:FallingSand,Block:"minecraft:command_block",Time:1,TileEntityData:{Command:setblock ~-3 ~ ~ minecraft:stone}}}}}}}},Riding:¬
{id:FallingSand,Time:1,Block:"minecraft:command_block",TileEntityData:{Command:unused},Riding:¬
{id:FallingSand,Time:1,Block:"minecraft:command_block",TileEntityData:{Command:give @p tipped_arrow 1 0 {Potion:strong_harming}},Riding:¬
{id:FallingSand,Time:1,Block:"minecraft:command_block",TileEntityData:{Command:effect @a slowness 0}}}}}}},Riding:¬
{id:FallingSand,Time:1,Block:"minecraft:command_block",TileEntityData:{Command:give @p bow 1 0 {ench:[{id:48,lvl:10}]}},Riding:¬
{id:FallingSand,Time:1,Block:"minecraft:command_block",TileEntityData:{Command:clear @p arrow},Riding:¬
{id:FallingSand,Time:1,Block:"minecraft:command_block",TileEntityData:{Command:effect @p strength 30 25}}}}}}
```

(this was pre-1.9, so it uses the Riding tag and doesn't have the auto tag; ¬ means it's all one line separated for readability)
This command places a bunch of command blocks to allow you to get "OP Arrows".
There you go, you have your own one-command creation!